# Check for at least one identical value in different column ranges based on ID

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to solve a problem in VBA and after a long time of browsing the web for solutions, I really hope someone is able to help me.
It's actually not a very hard task, but with very little programming and VBA knowledge as a new learner, I hope I can find a useful tip or solution with the help of the community.

So my problem is as follows:

I have a table with 3 columns, the first is filled with a number to use as an ID. Column 2 and 3 have different values that needs to be compared:
[image: picture]

What I'd like to do is select the range of column rows of column 2 and 3 based on the same ID. Once I have selected the relevant ranges of the columns, I want to compare if one name of column 2 matches one name of column 3.

So there is no need to have all names of the desired column ranges to match. One name match is enough. If a name matches, it should automatically fill in a new column "result" with 1 for match (0 for no match).

Do you have an idea, how I can select specific cells of a column based on an identifier?

```vb
    Dim ID_counter As Long
    ID_counter = 1
    
    If Cell.Value = ID_counter IN Range("Column1")
        Then Range("Column2").Select
        AND Range("Column3").Select
        WHERE ID_counter is the same
        
    In Column4 (If one Cell.Value IN Range("Column2-X:Column2-Y")
                IS IDENTICAL TO Range("Column3-X:Column3-Y"), return 1, else return 0

End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think you need VBA for this (certainly don't need to select anything). It could be done with COUNTIFS formula I think.

Comment: @SJR Not sure about that, because the ranges differ in their size, that's why I think it is necessary to select the range. And the data set I have is tooo long to solve this by hand...

Comment: Do you mean columns B and C are different lengths? I don't think that matters either. Just incorporate a check that B isn't blank.

Comment: @SJR, some cells of B are actually blank, for example B4, B6 and B9 as shown in the picture. The length of B and C do not differ, but based on the ID in Column A, the range of B and C that needs to be compared differ each time... hope it's kind of understandable...

Comment: Perhaps post a slightly larger sample? Why is there no 1 in row 3 or 10 - is that important?

Comment: @SJR One result per group.

Comment: @SJR yes, column2 with names1 indicates the name of one/several business owners, and column3  indicates the names of shareholders. What I want to find out is, whether one (or more) business owner is also a stakeholder or not. There are blank cells inbetween, because there are more information gathered to a business and therefore depending on the amount of information, some businesses have more rows than others, and the information is filled at the beginning of the excel file. The sample I posted is actually far in the back of the excel in columns AX and following..

Comment: @GSerg exactly!

Comment: OK so the 1s do not have to align with the duplicate entries? Is that just your example that the 1s are on the same rows as the duplicates?

Comment: It's trivial with two columns, e.g. put `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A2,$B$2:$B$10,$C2)` in D2 and `=IF($A2=$A1,"",COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A2,$D$2:$D$10,1))` in E2, and drag both down. Not immediately sure how to do with one column.

Comment: @SJR, oh that was just coincidence, it doesn't have to be next to the duplicates, but it just looks better, if it is in the first row of each new business, which is supposed to be indicated by the different underlying colors of the grouped rows

Comment: @GSerg, thank you for the input though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for your example so perhaps you can generalise it. The formula in D2 is

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,$C$2:$C$10))))
```

and is an array formula so must be confirmed with CTRL, SHIFT and ENTER.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SJR! Your solution does work, though at some point, it not only throws  0 = not true, 1 = true - but for whatever reason it also throws the number 1087... Must be related to the underlying data though. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

**Array alternative via **`Match()` function****

This approach compares the string items of columns `B` and `C` by passing two arrays (named `b`,`c`) as arguments *(c.f. section `[1]`)*:

```
chk = Application.Match(b, c, 0)
```

The resulting `chk` array reflects all findings of the first array's items via (1-based) position indices of corresponding items in the second array.

Non-findings return an `Error 2042` value *(c.f. section `[2]b)`)*; assumption is made that data are grouped by **id**.

```
Sub OneFindingPerId()
'[0]get data
    Dim data: data = Sheet1.Range("A1:D10")                 ' << project's sheet Code(Name)
    Dim b:    b = Application.Index(data, 0, 2)             ' 2nd column (B)
    Dim c:    c = Application.Index(data, 0, 3)             ' 3rd column (C)
'[1]get position indices of identic strings via Match() function
    Dim chk:  chk = Application.Match(b, c, 0)              ' found row nums of a items in b
'[2]loop found position indices (i.e. no error 2042)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(chk)                                ' omit header row
        'a) define start index of new id and initialize result with 0
        If data(i, 1) <> data(i - 1, 1) Then
            Dim newId As Long: newId = i
            data(newId, 4) = 0
        End If
        'b) check if found row index corresponds to same id
        If Not IsError(chk(i, 1)) Then                        ' omit error 2042 values
            If data(chk(i, 1), 1) = data(i, 1) Then           ' same ids?
                If data(newId, 4) = 0 Then data(newId, 4) = 1 ' ~> result One if first occurrence
            End If
        End If
    Next i
'[3]write results
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

First enter this user defined function in a standard module:

```
Public Function zool(r1, r2, r3) As Integer
    Dim i As Long, v1 As Long, v2 As String
    Dim top As Long, bottom As Long
    
    zool = 0
    v1 = r1.Value
    top = r1.Row
    
    '   determine limits to check
    
    For i = top To 9999
        If v1 <> r1.Offset(i - top, 0).Value Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    bottom = i - 1
    
    For i = top To bottom
        v2 = Cells(i, "B").Value
            If v2 <> "" Then
                For j = top To bottom
                    If v2 = Cells(j, "C").Value Then zool = 1
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
                    
End Function
```

Then in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",A2=A1),"",zool(A2,B2,C2))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

*(this assumes that the data has been sorted or organized by **ID** first)*

Comment: fyi an array alternative via `Match()` comparison of both column arrays +:)

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks for your help! Very appreciated!